# Make R Plot Axes the Same for Multi-Plot Figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have 3 multi-plot figures I'm making for a manuscript and R is shrinking the first plot in the 2 figures with 3 paneled plots. They have different axes and scales so I couldn't use a facet function, but ggarrange() does what I need. Is there a way to make the size of the actual graphs identical?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzIBU.jpg)

[Plot 1 axes smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzIBU.jpg)

Here's the script generating them:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)

summary_bp <- read.table("1500bp_amas_summary.txt", header=TRUE)
alignment_length <- summary_bp$Alignment_length
no_inf_sites <- summary_bp$Parsimony_informative_sites

Length_Site_Reg <- ggplot(summary_bp, aes(x=alignment_length, y=no_inf_sites)) +
                      geom_point(shape = 1, size = 1) +
                      geom_smooth(method = lm, size = 0.7) +
                      stat_regline_equation(label.x = 3000, label.y = 3500, geom = "text", aes(label= ..rr.label..), size = 2) +
                      stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 3000, label.y = 3100,aes(label = ..p.label..), size = 2) +
                      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1500, 15000), ylim = c(0,4000)) +
                      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1500, 15000, by=1500)) +
                      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4000, by=500)) +
                      labs( x = "Alignment Lengths", y = "Number of Parsimony \n Informative Sites") + 
                      theme(aspect.ratio = 1, axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1), 
                            axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), panel.background = element_blank(), 
                            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                            axis.text = element_text(size = 7), 
                            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9, face = "bold"), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8, face = "bold"))
Length_Site_Reg 

#Fig. 3b) GC hist

summary_all <- read.table("summary_trim.txt", header=TRUE, sep = ",")

GC_hist <- ggplot(data = summary_all, aes(x=GC_content)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.025, fill = "white", color = "black") +
  xlim(0.3,0.725) +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0,1050)) +
  labs(x = "GC Content", y = "Number of Orthologs") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1, panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.75, 0.65),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), axis.text = element_text(size = 8), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 9, face = "bold"), legend.key.size = unit(0.4, 'cm'),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.4, 'cm'),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.4, 'cm'), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=6),
        legend.text = element_text(size=6)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(GC_content), color="mean"), 
             linetype="solid", size=0.5, show.legend = FALSE) 
  
GC_hist


# Fig. 3c) K2P Divergence Hist
#trimmed_k2 <- file.choose()
trimmed_k2_data <- read.table("trimmed_alignment_k2.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",")
trimmed_k2_data

trimmed_k2_data_hist <- ggplot(data = trimmed_k2_data, aes(x=distance)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.025, fill = "white", color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0,1200) ) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1200,200)) +
  labs(x = "K2P Distance", y = "Number of Orthologs", size= 3) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1, panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 9, face = "bold")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(distance)), linetype="solid", colour="red", size=0.5, show.legend = FALSE) 
  
trimmed_k2_data_hist 

Fig3_plots <-ggarrange(Length_Site_Reg, GC_hist, trimmed_k2_data_hist, ncol = 3, widths = 1, heights = 1)
Fig3_plots
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `patchwork` package which does a very good job in aligning plots with differing axes, axis text, ...

Comment: [Cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/aligning_plots.html) is also a good option.   `cowplot::plot_grid(Length_Site_Reg, GC_hist, trimmed_k2_data_hist, align = "h", axis = "bt", ncol = 3, rel_widths = c(1, 1,1))`